# How to a call function after dismiss the Modal in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using modal and want to call a function after **dismiss the modal.**

i have tried `onDidDismiss()` method but it shows an error

```
async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modal.create({ component: UploadPage });
    modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
        this.getData();
    });
    return await modal.present();
}

getData() {
......
}
```

in this way i got an error `"Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onDidDismiss()` returns `Promise<OverlayEventDetail<any>>`.

Try as follows.

```
const modal = await modalController.create({ component: UploadPage });
const { data } = await modal.onDidDismiss();
if (data) {
   this.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers stated, now onDidDismiss() also returns a promise. So you can follow how documentation advises you to capture data or do something like this, its just another syntax basically:

```
async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modal.create({ component: UploadPage });
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

actual data will be inside data.data in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As per official document :

```
const modal = await modalController.create({...});
const { data } = await modal.onDidDismiss();
console.log(data);
```

See official docs [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#returning-data)